# Регистрация и запрет повторной регистрации IPB по данным ПК

Tags: ipb

Всем привет. На многих ресурсах видел такую наработку, мол когда регистрируется человек, запоминается не только его IP, но и все данные его ПК. И если его банят, то ему не удастся просто сменить IP, ему придётся менять ПК что бы повторно зарегистрироваться.

Вопрос: где можно найти такой скрипт для форума IPB. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете узнать только те данные которые отправляет браузер, а они легко подделываются через любой прокси или заголовки браузера. Бан по IP плох тем, что для тех у кого IP динамический, ваш бан не подействует, он переподключится к сети с новым ip и всего делов, зато пользователи которым его ip в следующий раз выдаст провайдер, к вам не попадут. Обычно банят просто учетную запись форума, которая естественно должна быть у каждого пользователя, в этом случае в бан попадает и email, тогда уже зловредам придется каждый раз регистрироваться заново не только у вас, но придется получать еще и новый почтовый ящик. Самый уникальный способ это привязка к мобильнику, но тут уж другая сторона, большинство участников форума просто пошлют вас куда подальше с такой политикой безопасности.

Comment: На сколько я помню, это стоит денег, отправка смс, в подтверждение тому, что именно ТЫ зарегистрировался на форуме

Comment: смс, как правило отправляются с форума скриптом или модератором, пользователь получает указанный секретный код, который он должен использовать для продолжения регистрации. Для отправки смс существуют различные бесплатные интерфейсы от операторов, напр. типа этого - https://sendsms.megafon.ru/ .Для автоматизации нужно получать API.